# Gt summary - How to delete the N's only on some rows of the table and keep the other one?

Tags: r, missing-data, gtsummary

I would like that for Test, Test2 ... Test7, that the N does not appear in the table.
But I can't do either select or filter and I can't find any solution to make it disappear but stay on the other variables of the table.
This a part of my code:

```
base %>%
  tbl_summary(include = all_of(var_interet),
              statistic =list(
                all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)",
                  Test ~ " ", 
                  Test2 ~" ", 
                  Test3 ~ " ", 
                  Test4 ~ " ", 
                  Test5 ~ " ", 
                  Test6 ~ " ", 
                  Test7~ " "),
              digits = list(
                all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1)
              ), 
              type = list(
                Q1_oui_systematique ~ "dichotomous", 
                Q1_non_temps ~ "dichotomous", 
                Q1_non_outils ~ "dichotomous", 
                Q1_non_aise ~ "dichotomous", 
                Q1_non_necessaire ~ "dichotomous", 
                Q1_non_autre ~ "dichotomous"),   
               sort = c(ID_type_centre, ID_repondant,presence_tiers1, Q1_oui_systematique, Q2_oui_mod_decouverte, Q4) ~ "frequency",
              missing = "no") %>%
  bold_labels() %>% 
  italicize_levels()%>%
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Ps**")%>%
  add_n()
```

My second question is how do you make the missing data dependent on the variables and not on the whole? because if i put missing = "ifany", for some of my data it's irrelevant because that just people who couldn't answer theses questions.

Thank you a lot for your answer, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you're trying to get achieve without the N for the test variables. But i've included an example with what you may be after.

You can use the `remove_row_type()` function to remove the missing rows for selected variables.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.1'

trial %>%
  select(age,
         death,
         test1 = response, 
         test2 = response) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    statistic = 
      list(death ~ "{n} ({p}%)",
           c(test1, test2) ~ "") # show no statistics for the test variables
    
  ) %>%
  # remove the missing row for the test variables
  remove_row_type(variables = c(test1, test2), type = "missing") %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 200** |
| --- | --- |
| Age | 47 (38, 57) |
| Unknown | 11 |
| Patient Died | 112 (56%) |
| Tumor Response |  |
| Tumor Response |  |

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>